# Dynamically editing html declaration javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I got my html document with the `<html>` tag, I want to dynamically insert stuff into that tag like

```
<html xmlns:fb="...">.
```

The reason for this is that I'm not allowed to touch the main file but am allowed to adjust it from within another file... Is this possible and how would I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's possible. `document.documentElement` is your `<html>` tag, and just use `setAttribute` (or `setAttributeNS`) on it.